# Intent about internet

Tags: java, android, android-intent

In my application I call intent GPS if it is off

```
private void GPS() {    
     Intent GPSSetting = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
     startActivity(GPSSetting);    
}
```

and i use it in button

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
    public void onClick(View view) {    
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);    
           if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){       
               method();    
           }else{
               GPS();
           }    
        }
    });
```

and it is works, but now i have problem with edit this for checking whether internet is ON

on start i make this:

```
private void internet() {    
    Intent internet = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(internet);    
}
```

but how to use it like a button including GPS ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet for checking whether network connection is available from [Determining and Monitoring the Connectivity Status](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#DetermineConnection):

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
```

Comment: first "contex" is underlined by AndroidStudio, on google is not explained how to fix it

Comment: If you're using this code inside an `Activity`, use `this` instead of `context`.

Comment: now "getSystemService" is underlined, but when i cut "this." is fine, it's good idea ?

Comment: it is almost works, but when i no have internet, app show me different settings with "network operators", i want to show options with the possibility of the inclusion of the Internet